# Drawing with touch html canvas only drawing dots

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Recently I have been working with responsive design and I decided I would make a page with some quotes and a place where you can then sign your name. The place where you can sign uses mouse and touch events to draw on canvas. It works perfectly with a mouse but with touch when I try to drag and draw it just highlights box but I can draw one dot at a time by tapping but I want it to drag normally like with the mouse. I have set default off for things however I still cannot fix this issue. I don't know if it has something to do with the canvas being highlighted with touch. Here is the individual code for the touch not in my site but in a canvas webpage by itself:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sketchpad</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
var ctx;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
var mouseDown=0;
var touchX,touchY;
function drawCircle(ctx,x,y,size) {
    r=0; g=0; b=0; a=255;//opaque
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+(a/255)+")";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
} 
function clearCanvas(canvas,ctx) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
    //get mouse position
function getMousePosition(moves) {
    if (!moves)
        var moves = event;

    if (moves.offsetX) {
        mouseX = moves.offsetX;
        mouseY = moves.offsetY;
    }
    else if (moves.layerX) {
        mouseX = moves.layerX;
        mouseY = moves.layerY;
    }
 }

function canvases_touchStart() {
    getTouchPosition();

    drawCircle(ctx,touchX,touchY,4);

    //prevents another mousedown
    event.preventDefault();
}

//draw and prevent default scrolling with touch
function canvase_touchMove(moves) { 
    getTouchPosition(moves);

    drawCircle(ctx,touchX,touchY,4); 

    //prevent scrolling
    event.preventDefault();
}


function getTouchPosition(moves) {
    if (!moves)
        var moves = event;

    if(moves.touches) {
        if (moves.touches.length == 1) { //one finger
            var touch = moves.touches[0]; //get info for finger
            touchX=touch.pageX-touch.target.offsetLeft;
            touchY=touch.pageY-touch.target.offsetTop;
        }
    }
}
function canvase_mouseDown() {
    mouseDown=1;
    drawCircle(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,4);
}
function canvase_mouseUp() {
    mouseDown=0;
}
function canvase_mouseMove(moves) { 
    getMousePosition(moves);
    if (mouseDown==1) {
        drawCircle(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,4);
    }
}



function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById('canvase');

    if (canvas.getContext)
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //check for ctx first 
    if (ctx) {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', canvase_mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', canvase_mouseMove, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', canvase_mouseUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', canvase_touchStart,    false);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', canvase_touchMove, false);
    }
}
</script>

<style>
#whole {
/*prevents highlighting text*/
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
#instructions {
width:30%;
height:15%;
padding:2px;
border-radius:4px;
font-size:120%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:center;
}
#board {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 1%;

}
#canvase {
height:300;
width:400;
border:2px solid black;
border-radius:4px;
position:relative; 
 display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 1%;
}
#clearbutton {
font-size: 150%;
padding: 2px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
background: green;
border: 1px solid black;
color:white;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<div id="whole">
    <div id="instructions">
         Sign name by tapping or dragging in box (draw slowly to  prevent single <br/><br/>
         <input type="submit" value="Clear Board" id="clearbutton" onclick="clearCanvas(canvas,ctx);">
    </div>
    <div id="board">
        <canvas id="canvase" height="300" width="400">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this issue or a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the `canvase_touchStart` event is causing the issue.

You may remove the line `canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', canvase_touchStart, false);` and the corresponding function `function canvases_touchStart() {...}`

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/aYvzzV)

Hope this helps.

*PS: To know how to create a smoother effect, you may refer to this [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/eVvpGq) as well.*

Comment: Thank you! Can you provide a quick explanation for this so I can have a better understanding I thought I needed to use touchStart

Comment: I believe the `touchstart` and `touchmove` eventListeners are having a conflict as the former prevents the latter. Moreover, if you use the `touchstart`, it won't let u tap and move as instead it will move the page as a whole. Hope it is clear for you now. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you I was stumped on it for so long trying to understand what was wrong. I guess it didn't occur to me this may have been a problem because of how the mouse works but at the same time I have to remember that touch and mouse do not work the same.

Comment: Glad that I could help. You may choose the answer as 'correct' if you find it helpful so that it would help other users as well. Thank you.